# What is the job title for a "car servant"?

Tags: word-choice

What is the job title for this man? (PS: Even it is short this question completely describes my problem, so this sentence is unnecessary)

[image: Job title]

Comment: I disagree that the problem is "completely" described here. If that's a rental car and he's opening the door for me to put my suitcase in, he's an _attendant_. If he's going to drive me somewhere, drop me off, and leave, then he's a _taxi driver_ or _shuttle driver_. If works for me personally and drives me wherever I want to go, he's a _chauffeur_. And if all he does is open the door for me, he could be a _doorman_ or a _footman_. From [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/doorman): **footman** (*n*.) a male servant whose job includes opening doors and serving food.

Comment: @J.R. His dress and the style of car eliminate those possibilities IMO, not to mention the absence of anyone else in the driver’s seat. I agree that OP could provide more context in order to get more specific answers (this is almost always the case), but the question is answerably clear as written.

Comment: Why couldn't a chauffeur be dressed without the jodhpurs and cap, just in a nice suit? Why can't the vehicle in question be simply a high-end sedan, and not a stretch?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I think that's a reflection in the driver's window. I certainly can't tell if there's anyone in the driver's seat or not.

Comment: @Tyler - Let's say I'm the one walking toward this car. If there's no one in the driver's seat, that could mean (a) the man in the picture will be driving, after he shuts the door, (b) I will be driving, after I put my luggage in the back seat, or (c) someone else will be driving, after she, say, returns from the rest room.

Comment: @J.R. Could also be a Valet.

Answer (score 3):

Most English speakers employ the French loanword “chauffeur” to describe this profession.

> A **chauffeur** is a person employed to drive a passenger motor vehicle, especially a luxury vehicle such as a large sedan or limousine.
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia entry for “Chauffeur”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauffeur)</sub>

You could also just say “driver”.

> **driver** *noun* \ˈdrī-vər\
>   : a person who drives a car, truck, etc.
>   
> : a person whose job is to drive a vehicle (such as a taxi, truck, or bus)
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster definition of “driver”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/driver)</sub>

Comment: The person isn't driving; he's just opening a door. We don't even know if he has a driver's license. ;^)

Answer (score 1):

If they are people who work in hotels and  performing services like this is a part of their job you can call them  "hotel valet".

Answer (score 1):

Chauffeur  - from the french.  Assuming the man will then drive the person to where he needs to go.

Comment: "from the [F]rench" -- literally the _fire_ man who stoked the boiler on an early steam-driven vehicle.